# Асинхронное выполнение PHP скриптов

Tags: php

господа, прошу совет

```
//PHP код
function one(){
    sleep(10);
    //что то делаем 1, ничего не возвращаем
}

function two(){
    sleep(20);
    //что то делаем 2, ничего не возвращаем
}

one();
two();
//эти скрипты будут выполняться чуть более 30 секунд
```

- если выполнить этот код - функции one, two - выполнятся последовательно. Есть ли какой то способ запустить обе функции ( или аж целый PHP файл путём обращения к нему, запуская, но не ожидая ответа ) так, что бы выполнение было в асинхронном режиме?

p.s.
мне на ум приходит только поднятие страницы HTML и обращение AJAX запросами - плохо, но работает. еще есть работа с сокетами - лучше, но интересует более простое решение. - такое решение есть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам по себе php синхронный язык. Есть популярный фреймворк для асинхронного кода, React PHP: https://reactphp.org/

Answer (score 2):

На сколько я знаю, php синхронный язык. Вы можете запустить в отдельном потоке через команду `exec("php /path/two.php 123")`